# How to track geolocation in html5 without prompting geo location sharing

Tags: html

Short:How to track geolocation in html5  without  prompting geo location sharing
Long: i wanna develop a website which tracking user location with out user prompting, is any way (like   can i use phone gap for gps co-ordinates)

Answer (score 2):

The geolocation warning is shown by the browser before sharing the location. This is a security measure and cannot be bypassed.

You could, however, get an approximate (and sometimes very inaccurate) location from the IP address using an API. There are many available, just try searching online.

Comment: but they are not accurate in our region

Comment: The most important part of my answer was the first part. I simply offered an alternative.